# Creating dynamically different cloned forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my HTML, I have a normal form. The form takes inputs and submits. The user will then click a button called "#addOne". This button, using jQuery, appends a cloned form to the previous form. Each form is numbered, and each form is one less than its previous. The numbers will be used in my SQL WHERE clause. I want the cloned forms to be separate forms, For example, if I enter values for form 9 and click submit, and then enter values for form 8 the information won't collide with each other. Form 8's button should not submit for all the other forms.

Here's my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2c2xL0cz/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="article_properties">
                        <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p><div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px"<p class="pageNumber"></p></div>
                        <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
                        <p>Image</p>
                        <input type="file">
                            <p>Subtitle</p>
                            <input type="text" name="subtitle">

                            <p>Text</p>
                            <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
                            <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
                        </form>

                        <div id="addOne" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange; border-radius: 50%"><p style="text-align: center; line-height: 25px">+</p></div>

                    </div> <!--End of article properties div-->
```

**jQuery/Ajax:**

```
var numPages = 10;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);
$('#addOne').click(function()
            {

                numPages--;
                        var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
                        $('.article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);
                        $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                        $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);

            });

            $('.article_properties_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Also, I do not wish to refresh the page when the form submits. For some reason, the dynamically created forms are creating page refresh when the submit button is clicked. There's also a solution in creating a div outside of the form elements, but this technique is making the forms think they're one form, but they should be separate forms all submitting to their respective pageNumbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$('.article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);
```

To the below one

```
$('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
```

**Right now you are appending the new form with in the old form. So the data will get collide. You have to append the form outside the old form. So append the new form to the old form's parent**

**For prevent page reload of new forms**

```
$('body').on('submit','.article_properties_form', function(e) {
    //Your code
});
```

**Or**

```
$(document).on('submit','.article_properties_form', function(e) {
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: This is working, but the page is refreshing for the dynamically created forms. How do I make them not refresh just like the first form?

Comment: @user2896120, I have edited the answer. The solution is there

Comment: Works great! One last question, is it possible to create unique errors for these forms? Like for example, let's say the user entered data for the first form, but for the second form he didn't. Is it possible to show an error for that form?

Comment: You can add an Id for each form represent the number of form. Then you can check with the number and throw error